# Angular 2/Typescript - how to find in which typescript line the exception was thrown?

Tags: typescript, angular

Let's say I see such error in console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
angular2.dev.js:23501 EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23501BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23512ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1185(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
angular2.dev.js:23501 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.onClick is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23501ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1194(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
angular2.dev.js:23501 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23501ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1197(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
angular2.dev.js:23501 TypeError: l_context.onClick is not a function
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_TodoInput_0.handleEventInternal (viewFactory_TodoInput:31)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent (angular2.dev.js:8036)
    at AppView.triggerEventHandlers (angular2.dev.js:10736)
    at eval (viewFactory_TodoInput:86)
    at angular2.dev.js:13905
    at angular2.dev.js:13254
    at Zone.run (angular2-polyfills.js:1243)
    at Zone.run (angular2.dev.js:13456)
    at NgZone.run (angular2.dev.js:13418)
    at HTMLButtonElement.outsideHandler (angular2.dev.js:13253)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23501ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1198(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
angular2.dev.js:23501 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23501ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1201(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
angular2.dev.js:23501 EventEvaluationErrorContext {element: button, componentElement: todo-input, context: TodoInput, locals: Object, injector: Injector}BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23501ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1202(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
simpleSearch.ts:42 includes a
```

From this information, I can guess that the error is in todoInput.ts file becuase there is such line:

at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_TodoInput_0.handleEventInternal (viewFactory_TodoInput:31)

But still - where exactly? I see option to comment out a file till there is no error thrown. But would be better to see instantly the line.

**Update:**
I found out that in the template I had this:

```
<button (click)="onClick(logMe.value)">Log input</button>
```

but onClick function did not exist in my class. But still I want line number for quicker search.

**Update:**
Is there not possible to do something with source mapping, like SASS?

Comment: this error simply shows error has been thrown at the time of `click` event binding somewhere in your .ts file

Comment: If the exception is thrown in Angular code, it can't always show the line of your code that caused the error. That's the disadvantage of declarative programming. The code that actually runs is being generated and often there is no 1:1 relation to your source anymore.

Comment: Sure some kind of source mapping might be added eventually. I wouldn't expect it anytime soon though (before Angular features have stabilized).

Comment: Do you try to set sourceMap to true in your tsconfig.json? This allows you to map ts lines to lines of compiled js files...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier - actually yes, sourceMap was set to true, and it shows correct lines of console.log messages in ts files

Comment: So you have the answer to your question with our comments?

Comment: If as one comment says - that its not possible to have this information, and he is right, then  I have the answer.